# What is the right way to create properties accessible in my template for form validation (in Angular)?

Tags: html, angular, forms, angular-forms

Context:
I have a LoginFormComponent in Angular. In this component i have a form with 2 properties, email & password. What i am trying to achieve is to create properties in this component that i can access in my template so i can do something like this `*ngIf="emailIsInvalid && emailIsDirty"` without having to do things like `emailControl?.value === ''`.

Currently i am stuck with a lot of properties in my component:

```
emailIsEmpty: boolean | undefined;
emailIsDirty: boolean | undefined;
emailIsInvalid: boolean | undefined;
emailValue: string | undefined;

passwordIsEmpty: boolean | undefined;
passwordIsDirty: boolean | undefined;
passwordIsInvalid: boolean | undefined;
passwordValue: string | undefined;

emailOrPasswordHasErrors: boolean | undefined;
```

That i update if there are changes:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.formGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
      this.updateEmailAfterChanges();
      this.updatePasswordAfterChanges();
    });
  }

  updateEmailAfterChanges(): void {
    this.emailIsEmpty = this.emailControl?.value === '';
    this.emailIsDirty = this.emailControl?.dirty ?? false;
    this.emailIsInvalid = this.emailControl?.invalid ?? false;
    this.emailValue = this.emailControl?.value ?? '';
    this.emailOrPasswordHasErrors =
      this.emailIsInvalid || this.emailIsEmpty || this.passwordIsInvalid || this.passwordIsEmpty;
  }

  updatePasswordAfterChanges(): void {
    this.passwordIsEmpty = this.passwordControl?.value === '';
    this.passwordIsDirty = this.passwordControl?.dirty ?? false;
    this.passwordIsInvalid = this.passwordControl?.invalid ?? false;
    this.emailOrPasswordHasErrors =
      this.emailIsInvalid || this.emailIsEmpty || this.passwordIsInvalid || this.passwordIsEmpty;
    this.passwordValue = this.passwordControl?.value ?? '';
  }
```

As i understand it it would be a performance issue to solve this like this:

```
get emailIsDirty(): boolean {
  return this.emailControl?.value === '';
}
```

Please help me find a solution that helps me keep my component lean and let me do presentation logic in my template, but also does not have unreadable code in the template checking the formcontrol it self.

Comment: It's not a performance issue at all, it's even the recommended way. 

Although, you probably do not need to test everything (touched, dirty, etc). Try reducing your logic first, then change your syntax.

Comment: MGX says is - it's not a performance problem. But you can use the validation of reactive forms, too. And then you can return form.valid as example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using getters or function calls into template - as you correctly mentioned - could be a bad practice in terms of performance, especially if the component has default change detection strategy and its template has a good amount of business logic into it!

There can be undesired change detection cycles, resulting sometimes in a laggy user experience.

If handled in a proper way, observables will be able to make your life easier (once familiarized with it, for sure ) and will make your apps more efficient.

What I would do is the following. I would create some derivated observables like this, and I would use them into the template using the `AsyncPipe` - so ensuring their unsubscription safely.

Also, I would go for changeDetectionStrategy OnPush in order to have a more fine-grained change detection and re-render only when each subscribed observables emit into the template (much more control than the "standard" way!).

```js
email$ = this.emailConfrol.valueChanges.pipe(
  distinctUntilChanged()
);
isEmailValid$ = this.emailControl.statusChanges.pipe(
  map((status) => status === 'VALID')
);
```

Also, you may also need to subscribe into the `.ts` sometimes, especially if your form component has complex business logic. When it is the case, I would suggest to always use takeUntil-destroy$ **as last piped operator** in order to avoid memory leaks and performance issues.
You can fine lot of guides regarding this topic. (i.e. [here](https://youtu.be/eJs4EJUOnNE))